# Asana api to upload attachment from Google Drive, Dropbox, Box

Tags: asana

We have implemented attachment upload from **computer**. Also we need to link files from cloud storage. The documentation shows for computer uploads only. Any idea on how to link files from **Dropbox, box.com Apis**.

Answer (score 0):

The Asana API doesn't currently support attaching from other services via the API (though you can retrieve file attachments from Dropbox and the others created via the desktop).

I'll add that to the list of feature requests.

Comment: Thanks for considering the request. Till then we will try to append attachment in the Description, like `Attached Files: http://dropbox.com/link-to-file`.